# Jetty shuts down program

Tags: user-interface, jetty

I am trying to create a GUI interface to start and stop a Jetty server with different return strings. Currently I have a start and stop button programmed and it returns "Hello World" into localhost:8080. My code is posted below, yes I have imports, removed to simplify it.

```
public class JettyGUI extends AbstractHandler{

private static Server server = new Server(8080);
private static boolean running = false;

private static void gui() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Jetty");
    JButton start_button = new JButton("Start");
    JButton stop_button = new JButton("Stop");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    panel.add(start_button);
    panel.add(stop_button);

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    start_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Start pressed.");
            startServer();
        }
    });
    stop_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Stop pressed.");
            JettyGUI.stopServer();
        }
    });

}


private static void stopServer() {
    if(running == false){
        System.err.println("Server is already running!");
    }
    else{
        try {
            server.stop();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Server stopped!");
}

private static void startServer() {
    if(running == true){
        System.err.println("Server is already running!");
    }
    else{
        try{
            server.setHandler(new JettyGUI());
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
      System.out.println("Server started!");  
    }
}

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    response.setContentType("text;charset=utf-8");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    response.getWriter().println("Hello World!"); //print this text

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    gui();

}

}
```

When I press the "start" button, Jetty API seems to take over my application and I can no longer press the "stop" button. Could anyone tell me a way to navigate around this or program this differently?

Thanks! :)
-Henry Harris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `server.join();` will make the current thread wait until the server is stopped.

Comment it out, as a GUI program you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks man. Simple but effective fix. Appreciate it. I'm just a noobie at programming.